# Can you still get duplicate queue messages using Beanstalk worker tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I've been trying to understand how the AWS Beanstalk worker tier operates internally but the documentation isn't very clear.

I'm assuming the Beanstalk daemon running on the EC2 instance has an internal buffer holding all the messages it's pulled off the queue (because it seems to hold a lot of messages in-flight at once). My question is, **is it still possible for a *single* worker to receive the same message multiple times due to at-least-once delivery?**

The Beanstalk documentation seems to suggest that it's still an important factor (or at least something to know about) but doesn't say anything concrete as far as I've seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Beanstalk will not change SQS guarantees and, although unlikely, it is possible to receive duplicates even on a single worker.